# Recommendations for a drive for live persistent boot for Linux distro

Tags: usb, linux, flash-drive

I'm having trouble running a standard Linux distribution that's been flashed as a live boot on my USB flash drive (USB 3.0, 8GB; BTW I've also tried with ADATA 1TB portable HDD but it was exceptionally slower). Specifically, when I try to run apps like VS Code or browsers, everything lags considerably.

As a result, can you suggest any USB flash drives that would be better suited for this purpose, or let me know what transfer rate I should aim for when buying a new one?

Should the USB flash drive be of 32GB or 64GB?

Comment: Hi Faisal, if you're looking to run the live environment from the drive regularly (rather than occasional tests/installs), your best bet is probably a purpose-built external SSD rather than a flash drive; these tend to be built using better flash and controllers than "flash drives." I typically recommend buying an M.2 NVMe drive and sticking it in an enclosure. Could you provide some additional detail on your budget, how much space you need, how many different ISOs you'd like to put on the drive simultaneously, and what types of computers you'll be booting on?